# Save the toggle state using share preference

Tags: android, toggle, sharedpreferences

I try to save the toggle state in my application.Here is my code

```
    boolean on;
public SharedPreferences spref;
ToggleButton tb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.fb_intermidiate);
    spref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    on = spref.getBoolean("On", true);  //default is true
    if (on = true) 
    {
      tb.setChecked(true);
    }       else
    {
      tb.setChecked(false);
    }
    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_back); 
    //back.setText(R.string.back_button_in_settings);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    }); 
} 

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

    on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "On : Notification will be Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("On", true); // value to store
        editor.commit();

    } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Off : Notification will be Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =spref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Off", false); // value to store
        editor.commit();
    }  
}
```

But Its getting force close.:(

Here is my logcat

```
07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start       activity ComponentInfo{com.ace.gugulog/com.ace.gugulog.activities.FacebookIntermidiate}: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)

07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)

07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)

07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at  com.ace.gugulog.activities.FacebookIntermidiate.onCreate(FacebookIntermidiate.java:32)

07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)

07-25 09:02:23.317: E/AndroidRuntime(640):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output?

Comment: Give us the stacktrace please.

Comment: Actually its a vast project.This is only a small portion.So its taugh to find the error

Comment: Surely on force close an exception must be thrown

Comment: check    if (on == true)  not sinlge =.

Comment: do my prefernc need to this mode? `spref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most likely source of error is, you are not using shared preferencces properly, change your code to: you should use getSharedPreferences instead of getPreferences method.

```
  boolean on;
public SharedPreferences spref;
final String PREF_NAME="preferences";
ToggleButton tb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.fb_intermidiate);
    spref = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    on = spref.getBoolean("On", true);  //default is true
    if (on = true) 
    {
      tb.setChecked(true);
    }       else
    {
      tb.setChecked(false);
    }
    back = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_back); 
    //back.setText(R.string.back_button_in_settings);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    }); 
} 

public void onToggleClicked(View view) {

    on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();
    if (on) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "On : Notification will be Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("On", true); // value to store
        editor.commit();

    } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Off : Notification will be Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =spref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Off", false); // value to store
        editor.commit();
    }  
}
```

Comment: what code of line is there on line number 32 in FacebookIntermidiate.java

Answer (score 0):

You should check the if condition if(on) or if (on == true). I am not what cause a problem but it is one of them

Comment: yes, this is incorrect, but this stmt cant throw an exception

Comment: i use this mode `if (on == true)`.Still force close

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

Boolean checkforFirstTime = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkforFirstTime", true);

    //Checking whether application is launched first time
    if (checkforFirstTime) {
        // Make boolean value "checkforFirstTime" to false
        editor.putBoolean("checkforFirstTime", false);
        editor.commit();
    }
    } else {
              // else part
    }
```